# Proof by contradiction - cubic equation has a root in the interval (N,N+1)

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

The question is you have to prove by contradiction

> The equation $x^3-3x^2-2x+3=0$ has a root in the interval $(N,N+1)$ where N is an integer. Prove that there are three possible values of $N$

I don't understand how to get started with this. $(N,N+1)$I think this means that the root will be between two consecutive integers so wont be a whole number so I cant use factor theorem? I am also stuck on what is the initial contradicting assumption is, is it "there are not three possible values of N" ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^{3} - 3x^{2} -2x+3$.

Note that $f(3) = -3$ and $f(4) = 11$, so $f(x)$ has a zero in $(3,4)$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem..

Similarly, $f(0) = 3$ and $f(1)=-1$, so $f(x)$ has a zero in $(0, 1)$. Also, $f(-2) = -13$ and $f(-1) = 1$, so $f(x)$ must have a zero in $(-2,-1)$.

Thus, $\boxed{f(x)\text{ has zeroes in }(-2,-1),(0,1),\text{ and }(3,4).}$

Comment: so do you just use trial and error to work it out? Do you know how to prove by contradiction as im still stuck on that bit, but i can see how your method works :)

Comment: You might be able to use contradiction to prove that there are no integer roots (testing with the Rational Root Theorem), but I can't see a way to prove that the function has $3$ unique real zeroes without the the Intermediate Value Theorem.